# How to set chromium-flags.conf?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, docker, chromium

I'm trying to make headless chrome the default on an Alpine docker container. It seems to work when I run `chromium-browser --headless` but putting `--headless` in `~/.config/chromium/chromium-flags.conf` doesn't seem to do anything.

Version: `Chromium 72.0.3626.121`

Answer (score 1):

It is [Issue 871027](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=871027#c2)
adding flags to cli only for now.